# Pandas: Get Max Value By Group With Additional Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I realize this is a very simple question but infuriatingly I am unable to figure this out. I want to group by position and return the maximum grandtotal value for each distinct position. This is easy. However, I cannot find a way to also include the player column in addition in the resulting dataframe. How can I create a dataframe that includes the one player with the max score for each position?

Given dataframe result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame([
{'position': 'Top', 'grandtotal': 36.72, 'player': 'Joe'}, 
{'position': 'Top', 'grandtotal': 101.18, 'player': 'Bill'},
{'position': 'Middle', 'grandtotal': 33.32, 'player': 'Jim'}, 
{'position': 'Middle', 'grandtotal': 72.62, 'player': 'Him'}, 
{'position': 'Bottom', 'grandtotal': 42.61, 'player': 'Tim'}, 
{'position': 'Bottom', 'grandtotal': 83.98, 'player': 'Slim'},])
```

I can return the position and the grandtotal with:

```
playerframe = result.groupby(['player', 'position']).sum().reset_index()
```

Giving me:

```
Top         101.18

Middle      72.62

Bottom      83.98
```

I just need the top scoring player's name included as well! It seems like it should be so simple. I'd like:

```
Top         Bill    101.18

Middle      Him    72.62

Bottom      Slim    83.98
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`loc`** with **`groupby`** and **`idxmax`**

```
df.loc[df.groupby('position')['grandtotal'].idxmax()]

   grandtotal player position
5       83.98   Slim   Bottom
3       72.62    Him   Middle
1      101.18   Bill      Top
```

Comment: Wow. That is so elegant and simple. I knew pandas had something sleek, it just takes me a lot of stumbling around to find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By using `sort_values` and `groupby` `agg`

```
result.sort_values('grandtotal').groupby(['position'],as_index=False).agg({'player':'last','grandtotal':'sum'})
Out[345]: 
  position  grandtotal player
0   Bottom      126.59   Slim
1   Middle      105.94    Him
2      Top      137.90   Bill
```

Based on your description, if only need the max value row for each group:

```
result.sort_values('grandtotal').drop_duplicates(['position'],keep='last')
Out[347]: 
   grandtotal player position
3       72.62    Him   Middle
5       83.98   Slim   Bottom
1      101.18   Bill      Top
```

Comment: It's possible that the data I provided is not fully representative of my "actual" data but I keep getting the wrong results from these formulas. There's some strange summing going on which produce higher values than they should.